# Cómo descargo una imagen de un streaming de una cámara ip usando jquery o javascript

Tags: jquery, stream

Tengo un *streaming* generado por una *cámara ip* y lo muestro con un código *html* de la siguiente forma

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.17:8081/" id = "ipcam">
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

cómo lo guardaría dándole *click* en ese elemento "`div"` usando *jquery* o *javascript*

Comment: Disculpa, estoy un poco confundido, hablas de guardar el streaming completo, o sea la grabación.

Comment: solo una imagen

Comment: lo puse en el título

Answer (score 0):

Simularé la *"generación del streaming"* con una etiqueta *img*, estático , y poder generar las imágenes  dependiendo del `click` en el *div*.

```js
var ob = document.getElementById('target');/*Div*/
var img = document.getElementById('ipcam');

/* Evento click del Div*/
ob.addEventListener("click",function(){
  /* Creación del Canvas*/
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 160; /* Ancho */
  canvas.height = 90; /* Alto */
  contexto.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 160, 90);
  this.appendChild(canvas);/* Añadimos el Canvas al Div*/
})
```

```html
<img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="200" height="200" id="ipcam">
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que conseguirte un código en backend que te permita obtener un mjpeg a jpeg. En este caso, como quieres en javaScript, te sugiero que uses NODEJS (en realidad no importa el lenguaje de backend que estés usando). Te adjunto el link [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-extractor](http://aqu%C3%AD) , el cual es el jpeg-extractor. Se instala así: 
`npm install jpeg-extractor`

y el código es el siguiente:

```
var request = require("regular-request");
var jpegExtractor = require("jpeg-extractor");
var fileOnWrite = require('file-on-write');

//var url = 'http://root:123@127.0.0.1:11164/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//     CAMBIAS POR LA DIRECCIÓN DE TU CÁMARA IP
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var url = 'http://192.168.1.17:8081'

var je = jpegExtractor().on('image', function (image) {
    console.log('--> ' + image.toString('hex'));
});

var cnt = 0;
var fow = new fileOnWrite({
    filename: function () {
        return 'file_' + (cnt++);
    },
    path: '_output/',
    ext: '.jpg'
});

request(url).pipe(je).pipe(fow);
```